# Calling methods from a class via another class which uses it

Tags: class, perl, oop

Created a Perl Module:

```
use ElectricCommander;
use strict;
use warnings;

package EC;

sub new
{
   my $class = shift;
   my $server = shift;
   my $self = {};
   bless( $self, $class );
   $self->{EC} = ElectricCommander->new($server);
   $self->{EC}->login("user", "password");
   return $self;
}
1;
```

In script, is there a way to call the methods which are in ElectricCommander module?
e.g, getJobStatus is present in ElectricCommander, can I do something like below?

```
use EC;
$obj = EC->new("myserver");
$obj->getJobDetails("1234");
```

Comment: That kind of sounds like you're trying to subclass `ElectricCommander`.

Comment: The `package` line should come first. This makes a big difference if `ElectricCommander` exports any symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composition seems suitable here: add methods to `EC` to dispatch to the other class's methods.

For instance

```
package EC;

use strict;
use warnings;

use ElectricCommander;

sub new { 
    ...
    $self->{EC} = ElectricCommander->new($server);
    ...
}

sub getJobDetails {
    my ($self, @args) = @_;
    $self->{EC}->getJobDetails(@args);
}
```

and you can call

```
use EC;
my $ec_obj = EC->new(...);
$ec_obj->getJobDetails(...);
```

You can also instantiate `ElectricCommander` as [class data](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perltoot.html#Class-Data) instead of in `new` so that its object is constructed once, when `EC` is `use`d. This is a design choice, whether you want `EC` instances to each have its own `ElectricCommander` object, constructed as they need it, or whether one object fits all `EC` objects' needs.

If `EC` were to truly extend `ElectricCommander` – to use most of its methods, override some and add more – then you could have it inherit from (subclass) the `ElectricCommander`.

Most of the time when you run into a need to use a class in another you want composition, sketched above, where a class uses capabilities of another (*has-a relationship*). Inheritance is suitable when you are building a carefully thought-out hierarchy of classes, where the parent lays down more general or abstract behaviors while its subclasses mostly specialize it (*is-a relationship*).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following to the `EC` package:

```
sub getJobDetails { shift->{EC}->getJobDetails(@_) }
```

If you have multiple methods of the kind, you can use build the wrappers dynamically.

```
BEGIN {
   for my $method_name (qw( getJobDetails ... )) {
      my $local_method = sub { shift->{EC}->$method_name(@_) };

      no strict qw( refs );
      *$method_name = $local_method;
   }
}
```

You could even redirect all calls to methods that don't exist in `EC` as follows:

```
use Carp qw( croak );

sub AUTOLOAD {
    my $method_name = our $AUTOLOAD;
    $method_name =~ s/^.*:://s;
    return if $method_name eq 'DESTROY';

    my $remote_method = $_[0]->can($method_name)
       or croak(sprintf("Can't locate object method \"%s\" via package \"%s\"", $method_name, ref($_[0])));

    my $local_method = sub { shift->{EC}->$remote_method(@_) };

    no strict qw( refs );
    *$method_name = $local_method;
    goto &$method_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make all methods of `ElectricCommander` available to instances of `EC` is to make `EC` a subclass of `ElectricCommander`:

```
package EC;
use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'ElectricCommander';

sub new
{
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_);
   $self->login("user", "password");
   return $self;
}

1;
```

Now

```
use EC;
my $obj = EC->new("myserver");
$obj->getJobDetails("1234");
```

should Just Work(tm).

Comment: Note: This transforms an encapsulation relationship ("EC has a ElectricCommander") into an inheritance relationship ("EC is a EletricCommander"). That may or may not be appropriate.